# How to change the background color in Windows Photo Viewer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8, colors, windows-photo-viewer

When you open a picture file in Windows Photo Viewer the default background color is white. This is just fine in most use cases. But you might find yourself in a situation where your picture is very bright and you might want to view it on a black or a grey toned background.

[image: a]

Or as in my situation I have a historic map that's been digitized at really high resolution. There is a white border surrounding the map sheet, and I need to remove that before I can import that file and start working with the map in a GIS system. The only problem is I can't see white on white. I don't know which files need editing and which ones do not.

So is there a way to change the background color in Windows Photo viewer?

Comment: If you see this color as white, you might want to check your color settings. ;) It's [#eef3fa](http://www.color-hex.com/color/eef3fa).

Comment: Haha, ok! Well it's a sort of "white". :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_white

Comment: Looking at this now... I don't think you guys understood the question. I was not asking this because the middle part of the picture (the actual map) appeared white for me... it didn't! It was yellow-ish... It's a 19th century map, what do you expect? It's nothing like Google Maps. I was asking because I wanted to customize the background that's used by Photo Viewer to create contrast. You can tell that there is a narrow white... or white-toned margin surrounding the map. I was not asking this with the purpose of working around this... supposedly common color profile problem in Windows.

Comment: For the record, all my monitors have their manufacturer supplied color profiles installed, and I do not recognize the problem you described. If you guys have a color profile problem, please post your own question about it. Don't provide solutions to that problem as the answer to my question. That's not my problem, and not what this question was about.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As it turns out, Microsoft has not foreseen the need for an option that would allow you to do this with two clicks. But thankfully there are kind and knowledgeable people who go one step further than Microsoft and share their solutions to common problems like these.

So the way you can change the background color is by editing your Windows registry.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key to open the Run prompt.
2. Type in `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click Yes if prompted
   by UAC.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo
   Viewer\Viewer`
4. From Edit menu, select New and then DWORD (32-bit). Name it
   `BackgroundColor`.
5. From Edit menu, select Modify.
6. Type in "ff" followed by the hexadecimal value for the color you
   want (e.g. `ff000000` for black).
7. Click OK and close the Registry Editor. Done!

When you open a picture in Windows Photo Viewer now you should see a black background color.

[image: b]

The white border is now better exposed and I can see what files need editing. A black background also makes your regular pictures (not many people are looking at maps in Windows Photo Viewer) pop out. It gives you better view of the picture and makes it easier for you to decide which ones to keep and which ones not to keep, in case you are culling photos inside Windows Photo Viewer. Some users might find that a grey background is a better choice, it's kind of the mid option between white and black.

Here's an example with a shade of green.

[image: c]

All the credit goes to [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/124566/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-windows-photo-viewer/). I just wanted to share this with you guys and give you an idea how this can be helpful. This has been tested and is working in Windows 8.0. Because [Windows Photo Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Viewer) has been included with Windows XP and Windows 7 it should work with those OS-es. In Windows Vista it was replaced by Windows Photo Gallery, so those users might need to find the proper registry key and then add the same DWORD value.

Comment: FYI, this feature has been available since Windows Vista: the photo viewer was called Windows Photo Gallery, and was later renamed in Windows 7.  This setting have since remained unchanged till Windows 8.1. In Windows Vista the registry key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery`. The actual value follows the [ARGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space#ARGB) format, but only fully opaque colors are taken into consideration (i.e. `ffxxxxxx`).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I can confirm that the key you posted is essentially correct. I still have one machine running Vista Ultimate 64-bit at home, so I took a peek inside the registry. Just remember to create the DWORD inside the sub-key `Viewer`. So that would be `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery\Viewer` instead.

Comment: Yes, the `Viewer` subkey is the same indeed. BTW, I can confirm it works in Windows 7 too. As for Windows XP, you could use a third-party viewer to workaround the limitation. Feel free to update the answer with the additional info I provided.

Comment: Verified working in Windows 10, exact instructions as explained above.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct, but if you enabled Photo Viewer on a fresh Windows 10 install by editing the registry, [as seen here](https://www.howtogeek.com/225844/how-to-make-windows-photo-viewer-your-default-image-viewer-on-windows-10/), there are a few extra steps. You will have to start by adding all the keys below `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\` as well as the new DWORD.

Select `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\`; Edit menu: New: Key; Name it `Windows Photo Viewer`.

Select `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer`; Edit menu: New: Key; Name it `Viewer`.

Comment: If you open Windows Photo Viewer at least one time and view a picture, those keys get created for you.

Answer (score -1):

Sivakumar's answer worked just fine; no need to edit registry.

To clarify his answer a bit:

- Click on start
- Type color management in the run line
- Click on “color management”

(or go to control panel color management)

Click on the advanced tab then click change system defaults

Click on add button

Select item starting with sRGB and click ok

It should show up in the list of profiles
Select sRGB under profiles and then click set as default profile.

After that close out the color management windows.
Open up the windows photo viewer (close and reopen if it is open) and the background should be the default pale blue-white again.

Comment: Whose? I only see [one other answer](http://superuser.com/a/719868) on here.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @bertieb The other answer has been deleted because it didn't answer the question (just like this one doesn't either).